# VBA passing variables

Tags: ms-access, vba

Im having trouble passing a value from form2 into form1. I want to be able to type a string in text0 of form2. When I click a button on form1, it should fill in the Form1.Text0 with Form2.Text0. I just get a message saying null.

Here's the code

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()

Dim box1 As Object
Dim feedBox As Object

Set box1 = Forms!Form1!Text0
Set feedBox = Forms!Form2!Text0

MsgBox "Feedbox is " & feedBox.Value


box1 = feedBox.Value

MsgBox "Box1 is " & box1



End Sub
```

Comment: aren't controls marked as "private" by default?  Perhaps exposing the data as a public variable will get you what you're after...

Comment: Forms are just glorified classes. Expose a property. That's exactly what I did with this code. I recommend taking a look at it. https://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/2014/03/08/progress-bar-for-ms-access/

Answer (score 0):

You only need this code.

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()
    Me.Text0 = Forms!Form2!Text0
End Sub
```

The Command button will reside on Form1, so the above code is very plainly doing what it needs to do. Just make sure the **Form2** is open. No need ot create any objects.

Comment: Thank you all. Stupid question....but when would I need to create the objects then?

Comment: @user229342, you do not have to anywhere. Form controls can be accessed from anywhere using the format shown above !